# I use a wifi network that is connected to my modem. How do I find out the address of the wifi router?

Tags: ip-address, router, modem

192.168.1.1 goes to my (Beetel) modem.

I'm unable to figure out how to access my router when I'm on wifi. Only if I disconnect the router from the modem, and then connect my laptop to the router via LAN, can I access my D-Link router.

Answer (score 1):

Check your router's settings. Several models have an option to enable/disable access by wireless clients (for security reasons).

Edit: with "access" I mean access to the router settings/configuration options.

Comment: Dead-on, here.  I was about to suggest some advanced work with `netdiscover` or a similar tool for finding the router, when I noticed the OP said he could get to it on wired connection.  This was going to be my next suggestion.